# Problems with request when I change a value by parameter in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, postman

I have a function that asks for a value per parameter from a table.
When the request is made there are some values ​​that are in the table that is not reading them, while others are.
All of them are in the table. So it shouldn't give null.

**function:**

```
  public function showMarketByGroup($idGroup)
    {
        $response = array('code' => 400, 'error_msg' => []);
        try {
            $karateka = Karateka::find($idGroup);
            if (!empty($karateka)) {

                $karatekasInMarket = $karateka->karatekasByGroupInMarket;
                return   $response = array('code' => 200, 'karatekas' => $karatekasInMarket, 'msg' => 'Get all karatekas by group in market');
            } else {
                return $response = array('code' => 401, 'error_msg' => 'Unautorized');
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $response = array('code' => 500, 'error_msg' => $exception->getMessage());
        }
        return response($response, $response['code']);
    }
```

This is the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoV6R.png) where I am referencing:

When the column of the `id_group` has a value of *3* or *4*, the answer is correct.
But with the other values ​​it enters an exception in Postman:

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "error_msg": "Unautorized"
}
```

Comment: Did you ```dd($idGroup)``` to check if the values are being correctly passed?

Comment: I'm sure it's a small mistake, Please update your post and add the relations between Market, Karateka & Group - we will help you out

Comment: I'm sure it's a small mistake, Please update your post and add the relations between Market, Karateka & Group - we will help you out

Comment: Yes, the values are correctly passed